# Connecting RAW NAND through GPIO

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, device-tree

I'm trying to define a device tree for connecting an external raw NAND using GPIO on RPI3. 
I found that there are available drivers, and I found an  example in the sources' "Documentation" directory 
(Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mtd/gpio-control-nand.txt)
Yet, while using this example, I couldn't find how to define the **banka** label that appears there, and although DTB compilation doesn't fail, when trying to load the device tree (using dtoverlay command) it fails to load with issue on this **banka** component.
I found a **banka** declaration on pichochip dts file, but it when trying to copy it to my dts, it doesn't compile.
Moreover, I couldn't find how am I suppose to connect the RAW NAND to the GPIO connectors, which pins to use (specifically the data/address pins, which are supposed to be "address mapped").

Can any one point to a solution for that? I am struggling this issue for a couple of days now...

Thanks.

Comment: You probably should include your version of [that sketch](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/mtd/gpio-control-nand.txt) to give people some clue of how you are trying to adapt it to the Raspberry Pi. I know pretty much nothing about DTOs -- I think there are a few people here who should be able to help with the GPIO addressing -- but my hunch is with this you have to interface with the kernel's [MTD layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_Technology_Device) (is the standard Pi kernel even compiled for this?) see e.g., `common.txt` in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks for your reply.
Obviously, that sketch is what I used trying to add the DTS, but it doesn't work.
The MTD layer is already ready to get a GPIO-ASSISTED-NAND, but the Device tree is what I can't define correctly.

Comment: Perhaps ask on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=107